# Java Project Configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm curious as to what other people use in the Java world for configuring their applications.  I've previously used Spring's [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html) to load various properties files and bind them using the default Spring property editors.

This is a perfectly acceptable solution for what I've done, but I wondered is there was a better alternative for application configuration that somebody has used?

If you have used a better approach could you provide a list of advantages of using a Spring approach.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not strictly looking for solutions using Spring here... other solutions are perfectly acceptable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try something like [Constretto](http://constretto.org/), which handles different environments (test, acceptance, production etc) a little more gracefully.

Before diving into Constretto also be advised that [Spring 3.0](http://www.springsource.com/) *is* changing this landscape quite dramatically, with spring-el being the first thing that comes to mind. Even today the documentation [spring 3.0-M3](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/milestone/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.0.M3-with-docs.zip) reveals quite a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring, the approach you've adopted IS the best. Otherwise you'd have to load property or XML files yourself.

Comment: Sure, my question is what are the other alternatives though... not necessarily using Spring.  I'm not asking whether I have chosen the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I like spring's PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer and have used it on most of my projects. What I like most about it (and Spring in general) is that it is very flexible. For example, I have used it along with Jasypt to provide database username/passwords to datasources I configure using spring even when the passwords are stored in the property file in an encrypted format.

A good example of this technique is illustrated [here](http://heuristicexception.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/secure-your-spring-application-configuration-with-jasypt/)

Comment: Ooh.. Jasypt is what I am looking for on a project we are doing - thanks!

Comment: this thread may provide some good insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258299/best-practices-for-storing-database-passwords/421684#421684