# Using Kerberos to encrypt credentials / What is a static secret for a principal

Tags: java, encryption, kerberos, credentials, jaas

An application written in Java needs to store passwords to external services per user. Within the application the user itself authenticates against a KDC using Kerberos (basically creating a LoginContext utilizing [Jaas](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html)).

I would like to store the encrypted secrets to other services in some kind of file (XML?) at the applications location. Secrets could be login/password combinations to not Kerberos enabled Databases (MySQL...). Is there a better approach than the one I suggest - maybe a better location to store the information?

Is it possible, to use some of the already existing information from LoginContext to encrypt data in such a way, that only the same Subject (person or service) can decrypt the information?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to rephrase the question a little. Basically what I need is some kind of secret, that can only be received by an authenticated user.  Is there something like this?

Otherwise I would probably use some kind of salted hash of a subjects name as a secreat. I know this can be guessed, but it provides additional secruity to solutions as proposed e.g. in [What is the best way to keep passwords configurable, without having them too easily available to the casual human reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258299/439692).

Comment: Best practice for storing passwords "not" to store them. That is a security hole after all. Better approach would be enable kerberos login for mysql or linux machines or any service you use and use keytab/CC file for all credentials. It is now industry standard to use keytab files for all login, and expire them around 8 hours or 1 day.