# Hashing a password before putting it into a database

Tags: password-encryption

I am working on a project where we are using a custom user table.  This table contains a password field.  At the moment we save the plain text password into the database.  what I want to ask is how do I save a hash of the password to the table instead?  I have read about the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class but I don't know how to use this and how to generate salts and what the entire process is from start to finish.

Can you tell me what approach I might take?

Will each row in the user table need a salt value and if so where do I get this from?

Comment: What is a "databasept" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) / `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. If you just need it for hashing passwords, have a look at [SimpleCrypto.Net](http://www.shawnmclean.com/blog/2012/04/simplecrypto-net-a-pbkdf2-hashing-wrapper-for-net-framework/), which is basically a thin wrapper around `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

With SimpleCrypto.Net, you hash a user's password like this:

```
private ICryptoService cryptoService = new PBKDF2();

private void SetNewPassword(User user, string newPassword)
{
    //a new password hash is generated from a generated salt with the default settings
    user.Password = cryptoService.Compute(newPassword);
    //assigning the generated salt to the user
    user.PasswordSalt = cryptoService.Salt;
}
```

To check if a user entered the right password, you compute the hash with the same salt and compare it with the one you stored in your database:

```
private bool ValidatePassword(User user, string password)
{
    //hash the password with the saved salt for that user
    string hashed = cryptoService.Compute(password, user.PasswordSalt);
    //return true if both hashes are the same
    return hashed == user.Password;
}
```

Another possibility for securely hashing passwords is [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). There is an implementation called [BCrypt.Net](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -2):

Storing the password in a plain-text field is not a good idea.

Please refer to : [What is the best way to keep passwords configurable, without having them too easily available to the casual human reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258299/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-passwords-configurable-without-having-them-too-eas)

Comment: The answer you linked does not apply to this question.